# How to use key-enter trigger in oracle forms10g

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using oracle forms 10g.
I have used key-enter trigger.
I have created 3 text fields in which 2 are for inputs and 1 for result.
i want show addition of 2 i/p in result field.
I have used key-trigger for addition but when i pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> key it doesn't works.

Comment: Post your code for the triggers. For which fields have you put the trigger?

Comment: :T3 := :T1+T2;here T1,T2 and T3 are the names of my text fields

Comment: You haven't mentioned for which fields you've put the trigger. Where is the cursor when you're pressing enter?

Comment: Sorry,on T3. I have applied trigger on T3

Answer (score 0):

If you want a calculation to be done whenever either of your two input fields are changed, I suggest you put your code in `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` triggers, one on each input field.